# TFS shortcut to compare a modified file with the latest version

Tags: tfs

Right now I have to pull up Pending Changes window, right-click on the file and select Compare->With Latest Version...   Is there a faster way to look at my modifications?

Comment: Faster how?  You needn't necessarily go to Pending Changes window - you can also select that compare option from the context menu in an editor window, or from Solution Explorer.  But are you looking for a shortcut key?  Or tooling from the command line?

Comment: I worked with SVN before. In SVN pending changes window, I can just press enter on the selected file and see the mods. That was nice since I don't have to use the mouse at all and I can go through my list of changed files much faster.

Comment: If you have the file open in the Editor, you can perform a compare from the Context Menu.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

### Keyboard Shortcut for doing TFS Compare

In the *Team Explorer* window under *Pending Changes*:

- <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> on file

  - will compare the files
- <kbd>shift</kbd> + double click on file

  - will compare file in background
- Create visual studio mapping for the commands:

> Set the shortcut for compare folder under Source Control
>   Explorer, you should set the shortcut keys for **File.TfsFolderDiff**
>   command.
>
> Set the shortcut for compare specific file under
>   Source Control Explorer, you should set the shortcut keys for
>   **File.TfsCompare** command

Note: To set the keyboard shortcuts, open "Tools > Options".  In the dialog that opens, go to "Keyboard".  Example:

Note: The folder compare shortcut is only valid from the "Source Control Explorer".  It is the same as right clicking in the "Source Control Explorer" and selecting "Compare...".

[image: How to apply keyboard shortcut]

### References:

- [Keyboard shortcut for File Compare?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsversioncontrol/thread/d77933af-57ae-428f-adbc-9f5a0bdf92c6)
- [Comparison keyboard shortcuts for Pending Changes in TFS](http://alexmg.com/comparison-keyboard-shortcuts-for-pending-changes-in-tfs) by Alex Meyer-Gleaves.
- [How to Double Click to Diff Pending Changes in TFS](http://www.richard-banks.org/2010/07/how-to-double-click-to-diff-pending.html) by Richard Banks
- [TFS Shortcut to do a diff on all modified files with latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8594569/590956)

Comment: New Url for the second link: http://alexmg.com/comparison-keyboard-shortcuts-for-pending-changes-in-tfs/

Comment: tf diff was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Might want to mention at the top of the answer that shortcut keys refer to the Team Explorer window. I'm assuming that's correct because that's when it worked for me. So Glad I found this.

Comment: @TonyL. feel free to edit the post and I'll approve.

Answer (score 27):

You can switch the double-click behaviour in the pending changes window to do a compare with latest by changing a registry setting:

```
Path:  HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<ver>\
                               TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Behavior
Value: DoubleClickOnChange (DWORD)

0 == view as the primary command (default) 
1 == compare as primary command
```

You can find more information here:

- [How to Double Click to Diff Pending Changes in TFS](http://www.richard-banks.org/2010/07/how-to-double-click-to-diff-pending.html).

A comment on that post also shows the entry to set if you want to use a shortcut key to do the comparison instead.

Comment: Just a note that, currently double clicking a file in the pending changes window opens the file . After making the above change, you will have to right click the file and then choose Open to open the file in the editor window.

Answer (score 3):

You can add hotkey bindings for TFS context menu commands, which may be an approach that will work for what you need.

Go to Tools > Options > Keyboard. In the 'filter' field, type 'TFS' and it'll show a list of all TFS commands that you can bind hotkeys to. The Source Control comparison ones can be shortlisted with "CompareWith". I've bound hotkeys in this way to the pending changes window's context menu, which is a great timesaver versus working your way down that tortuous context menu, but there may be other options that suit your needs better.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative could be to set up an alias in Command Window and use it. To bring up the compare window:
Open Command Window (ctrl + alt + A)
Set alias for File.TfsCompare

```
alias diff File.TfsCompare
```

Next time you need to do the compare, type 'diff' and hit enter in the command window. 'diff' is an alias name, could be set to whatever of your choice. If you want to delete alias, use

```
alias aliasName /d
```