# Faster way to compare changes made in Changeset for TFS Source Control

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, source-control-explorer

IF I have a large changeset and want to be able to compare all changes before checking them in, is there a faster way than manually clicking compare to latest on every file?  I have something like 900 files I changed, and that seems veryinefficient.  There has to be a way to open all files in compare and be able to click close or ignore on each file one by one.

Best way to compare large changeset vs existing code?

Comment: There are additional suggestions that I think you'll find helpful in this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594569/tfs-shortcut-to-do-a-diff-on-all-modified-files-with-latest-version. Be sure to check out the "Diff all Files" extension.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open a Visual Studio Command Prompt (All Programs | Visual studio | Visual Studio Tools | Developer Command Prompt

(this is just a normal command prompt but with some extra env variables set, and with the visual studio tools in your path).

use the cd command to switch directory to the root directory that your project is in on your local disk that you want to compare:  example: cd \MyProjects\TheProject

execute this command:

```
tf folderdiff . $/The/Tfs/Folder/Path/To/Corresponding/ProjectDir/On/Server /recursive /view:different
```

(there is a space between the "folderdiff" and the ".", and another space between the "." and the $/  The "." just says "use the current local path (you should be sitting on it).  Being on the current path also gives the TFS command the context that it needs so that it knows how to connect to your TFS server, and which team project and collection to use.