# TFS tool to show file changes when getting latest?

Tags: tfs, version-control

I know I can look at the "Source Control - Team Foundation" output in the Output window but it's hard to tell where the results from the current request begin and the last request ended sometimes, and any files that I want to compare that are in the list I have to go look up.

In the past when I used subversion, I had a tool (I think tortoise) that did an awesome job showing me all the files that were changed and I could click directly on them to compare with latest version. I would often use this to do quick code reviews, and it made it much easier to make sure I wasn't about to get an updated project file that had been improperly merged.

Are there any extensions/plugins or anything that can help with this for TFS when getting latest?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Am I correct in assuming that you're using TFVC and not Git?

Comment: Using Visual Studio 2013... I'm assuming version of TFS is same but I will verify when I can take a look tomorrow. And yes we are using tfvc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't such a tool can exactly achieve that, there is a [user voice submitted here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/5630060-hook-into-on-get-latest-to-encourage-code-awarenes), and it's ARCHIVED.

Based on my experience, the best thing to do is a **folder comparison** before you get the latest version. In Source Control Explorer, you can compare the differences between two server folders, two local folders, or a server folder and a local folder. Right click on the target folder and select Compare. Read more [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/5630060-hook-into-on-get-latest-to-encourage-code-awarenes).

To see the changes block you can introduce the third compare tools. (e.g BeyondCompare, ExamDiff, [Code Compare](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DevartSoftware.CodeCompare) etc, you can reference my answer in another thread : [Visual Studio TFVC Merge Lines Misaligned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47930168/visual-studio-tfvc-merge-lines-misaligned/47937841#47937841)). In short you can get the change list from Output window, then compare each file accordingly.

Besides, you can also try using the **[Tf Command Line Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands)** and the Visual Studio extension [Diff All Files for VS2013](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=deadlydog.DiffAllFilesforVS2013). Reference this thread for details : [TFS Shortcut to do a diff on all modified files with latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594569/tfs-shortcut-to-do-a-diff-on-all-modified-files-with-latest-version)

Comment: Ok thanks. That's what I was afraid of. Currently I look at output window as you mentioned and manually look or sometimes I'll go to look at changesets before I get latest. Thing about it is that with SVN it was so quick and easy that it wasn't a waste of time to review code like really often and give feedback to other developers often. The extra minutes of time involved with doing it on TFS makes it a once in a while thing.